# How to lock revisions of a Google Spreadsheet that relies on another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

## Background

I usually link spreadsheets together to hide sensitive information. For example I have a Project Manager fill in the hours (in sheet A) of engineers and mark their work acceptable or not etc, then I link that same sheet to another sheet (sheet B) that also includes the hourly wages of the said engineers, and calculates the total pay. Sheet B will only be shared by the accounting team.

## Problem

A powerful and very useful feature of Google Sheets is the ability to track changes in the [revision history](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en) (similar to Git). However consider this scenario in [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin):

`given` spreadsheet A has a single sheet titled `hours`
`and` spreadsheet B has a `importrange("A","hours!A:C")`
`and` many revisions have been added to both sheets A and B
`and` spreadsheet B's structure has changed to include sheets `january` and `february` instead of just expenses
`when` user goes to sheet B revisions
`then`
**expected**
user should see all the revisions just fine
**actual**
the revision that has a broken dependency loads for ever

Comment: It's not clear to me if you are looking for a fix to the way that Google Sheets revision history works (I think this is offtopic on this site) or if you are looking for an alternative to the built-in revision history. By the other side I don't understand "the revision that has a broken dependency loads for ever". What do you mean by "broken dependency" and by "loads for ever"? (I'm sorry I use only the very basic features of GitHub and use them as a Web app)